GetDisplayUrl not getting correct http scheme
Background:
I am trying to get my endpoint URL from HttpContext for attribute validation work where the URL needed to be fully identical. The problem happens when I try the get the full URL, where the scheme will always be http instead of https.
During testing using Postman, my GET URL is https.
e.g https://endpoint/id?access_token=xxx
Code sample:
   public ProofKeyContextFactory Create(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
    var endpointUrl = httpContext.Request
            .GetDisplayUrl()
            .ToUpperInvariant();
    _logger.LogInformation("Endpoint URL: {EndpointUrl}", endpointUrl);
   }

When I check log (in Lens), the endpointUrl will be HTTP://ENDPOINT/ID?ACCESS_TOKEN=XXX instead with HTTPS.
I tried using httpContext.Request.Scheme but still returning https
What cause the SSL scheme to be terminated?
EDIT for more context, here most of the implementation:
public class ProofKeyContextFactory
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProofKeyContextFactory> _logger;

    public ProofKeyContextFactory(ILogger<ProofKeyContextFactory> logger)
    {
        logger.ThrowIfNull();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public ProofKeyContext Create(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
       var endpointUrl = httpContext.Request
                .GetDisplayUrl()
                .ToUpperInvariant();
        // Log information
        _logger.LogInformation("Endpoint URL: {EndpointUrl}", endpointUrl);

        //assign it to my public sealed record to use later
        return new ProofKeyContext(endpointUrl); 

    }
}

Then I register it in my StartupExtension.cs
private static IServiceCollection AddProofKeyContext(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ThrowIfNull();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<ProofKeyContextFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IProofKeyContext>(provider =>
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.ThrowIfNull();
            var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<ProofKeyContextFactory>();
            return factory.Create(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext);
        });

        return services;
    }


Could you please tell me how you use this  ProofKeyContextFactory method? If I directly use it inside the controller it works well. Like this.

@BrandoZhang I use it inside my custom attribute. The attribute then is put in controller class above endpoint method.

Could you please share your custom attribute code to let me test for it?

I test with your codes it still is right, it return the right. Result
